# Karaf + JPA: how to get an instance with injected property using blueprint.xml?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint

Example from hibernate official documentation.

```
 <bean id="dpService" class="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointServiceImpl">
    <jpa:context unitname="data-point" property="entityManager"/>
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
  </bean>
  <service ref="dpService" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointService"/>
```

Could you give me some examples how to get this DataPointServiceImpl with already injected EntityManager from container?

**UPDATE**

I tried this

blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">  
<bean id="myActivator" class="ru.bia.karaf.web.Activator" init-method="test">
        <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManager"/>
    </bean>
    <reference id="entityManager" interface="javax.persistence.EntityManager"/>
</blueprint>
```

Activator.java

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    EntityManager  entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void test(){
        System.out.println(entityManager);
    }
...
    }
```

but now I get

> ERROR: Bundle org.apache.aries.jpa.support [204] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.AriesTransactionManagerImpl cannot be cast to javax.transaction.TransactionManager)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.AriesTransactionManagerImpl cannot be cast to javax.transaction.TransactionManager

Answer (score 2):

Via OSGi Services you don't "get" the Impl you "only" retrieve the service provider via its API which in your case is the DataPointService.

If that's what you want, it's straight forward:

```
<reference id="pointService" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointService"/>
```

This will give you the reference to the service. If you rather would like to have direct access to the entitymanager, do the same with the entitymanager interface.

To do something on startup you'll need to define the init method to call after the bean has been fully initialized:

```
<bean id="myConsumingBean" init-method="init">
    <property name="dataPointService" ref="pointService">
</bean>
```

Might also want to take a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-osgiblueprint/)

**UPDATE:**
The error you see might be a result of two different interfaces available to your system. Check which bundles actually provide this interface, or if this interface is located inside your own bundle.

The latter might happen if you depend on the *javax.persistence.EntityManager* providing in your maven project with scope compile. Scope Compile (which is the default if not set) usually results in embedding those dependencies inside your own bundle. Make sure to set it to scope provided, that should fix your issue.

**UPDATE 2:**
Please don't use a bundle activator for this, you can't have blueprint and bundle activators mixed. 
You should use a std. Java class for this. Basically blueprint behaves like spring and therefore the blueprint.xml is kind of like an bundle activator. 
Cause if you mix the both, you'll have the result that your class isn't properly created.

Comment: I did that 

`<reference id="pointService" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointService"/>
  <reference id="myEntityManager" interface="javax.persistence.EntityManager"/>` 

but in Activator onStart() I stil get null 

`ServiceReference dataPointServiceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference("pointService");
        ServiceReference entityManagerServiceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference("myEntityManager");`

Comment: erf ... you can't mix blueprint and classic OSGi Activators ... maybe you should add some more details to your question?

Comment: I need to access database using Hibernate on bundle start

Comment: then you'll need to add a init function to your service consuming bean, which will be called after the dependencies are injected.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I got rid of exception by uninstalling gemini-blueprint feature and keeping only aries-blueprint. Now init-method is being called, but my entityManager is null